# Best practice to clip content to rounded cornered DIV Element

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on recreating Apple's iOS 5 Toggle Switch in HTML5 and CSS3. The key is that due to requirements, the composition cannot be made up of any images whatsoever. I have been able to achieve almost everything that I wanted, however there seems to be an issue with cropping the container box so that it only displays half of the toggle at a time.

Here's a screenshot to help explain what I mean:

[image]

Notice that the pink border (added only for development purposes) is rounded, but the content which extends past it seems to break out of the border-rounding. Can anyone suggest a suitable method by which I can prevent the content from expanding past the border-radius - effectively cropping the content of that `div` to fit inside the rounding?

I am currently thinking that this could be achieved using the `-webkit-mask-box-image` property, and image data URLs (for example somethin like: data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7). Is there a better solution, or can anyone offer help on creating these data URLs?

I hope that makes sense, and any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe this is a design flaw with webkit.  The content is never clipped to the border radius.  As for base64 encoding, I've found [this tool](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) helpful

Comment: Thanks! Using the base64 encoding tool you shared I was easily able to create a mask that works great.